# SVG in Safari: Element positioned incorrectly when translated

Tags: svg, safari

I am trying to make an SVG shape a dropzone, and it works perfectly in Chrome/Firefox, but when testing on Safari I have come across a strange behaviour which I am looking for a way to get round.

The problem (shown in the code below and this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tp5e98rs/) is that when the viewBox width/height does not match the view port width/height (the first SVG), a translated element is not positioned correctly when viewed in the inspector. If you inspect the first rectangle, the blue highlight is not directly over it, but if you inspect the second rectangle the blue highlight is, as you can see in the attached image. The difference between the two SVGs is that in one the viewbox doesn't match the view port, and in the other they do match. If you do the same in Chrome, the highlight is correct in both cases.

This is a problem for making dropzones from translated rectangles, because the dropzone ends up being where the incorrect highlight is shown.

Any ideas of a workaround to fix this problem?

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <rect transform="translate(20 20)" width="100" height="100" fill="#aaeeee"></rect>
</svg>

<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <rect transform="translate(10 10)" width="50" height="50" fill="#aaeeee"></rect>
</svg>
```

[image]